Is it possible to add a customer footer to Quill Editor
I'm trying to implement a rich text editor with a custom footer. Within the footer there will be some customer menu buttons and a send button that allows the user to send the text to the server.
Here is an example Mockup that illustrate the idea
I looked through the document on Quill website but don't understand if this is possible. Does any one have any insights/examples?
